# Compositor Glare Node

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes

I have recently been learning the compositor feature and have been running into some confusing issues. When i connected the glare feature to add glow to a scene, absolutely nothing happened...

also i recently made another scene where i have multiple glowing objects and **all but one is glowing**?!?!?! see attached image.

I've used glare multiple times now with no problems but twice now i ran into this problem.

thank you in advanced!

[image: scene with missing glow][image: Node Setup]

[image: Updated Glow]

@GordonBrinkmann

@Daniel - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UlLXuRFI9rgjxSwlm8Kr1q2K2dvb0YtG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi. If you haven't already figured out the answer, please add the .blend file

Comment: Have you tried reducing the _Threshold_ value in the _Glare_ node? 5.3 seems quite high for those not really strong emissions... And I think there are two glowing, the green and the yellow one  ;)

Comment: updated photo with adjusted threshold and .blend file with assets added. thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about all of your scenes. But in the screenshot the emission of your glowing objects doesn't seem very strong, but the *Threshold* in your *Glare* node is set to 5.3 which is quite high.

Here's an example: the following cubes have three different colored emission shaders, each with a different strength. The red has a strength of 2, the blue one a strength of 4 and yellow only 1.

[image: glow colors]

They look not to different in brightness although they are, which of course depends partially on their color. If you now plug the image into a *RGB to BW* node which sets R = G = B according to the brightness, it looks like this:

[image: bw values]

Although the yellow emission has a strength lower than blue and red, it has the highest value. And especially important: although they all have an emission strength of 1 or higher, all values are below 0.8 which is relevant for the *Threshold* of the *Glare* node.

Since no value of any emission was 0.8 or greater, setting the *Threshold* to 0.8 allows no glow on any of the three cubes.

[image: threshold 0.8]

But if you lower it to 0.7, a value that blue and yellow exceed, the glow starts to show on those cubes. The red one is still to dim.

[image: threshold 0.7]

Actually I don't know why the blue glow looks more intense than the yellow one, maybe because once the threshold is passed, the higher strength plays a role as well. But apart from that it's important that your threshold is low enough to let the emission through. An emission strength of 5 doesn't necessarily mean it's really brighter than 4 (unless it's pure white I guess).

Here's just one tip how I usually add glow to my images. In the *Glare* node I set the *Mix* value to 1, this way it only outputs the glow effect. Then I add it to the image by plugging it in the second socket of a *Color Mix* node. This way I can use the factor to reduce the glow if it's too intense, but also boost it by setting the factor higher than 1.

[image: glow mix]

**EDIT:** Now I've downloaded your file and worked a little on it. First of all here are some things about your *Compositor* setup: the *Mix* factor in your *Glare* node is still on 0.3, which means you don't have the glow separately on the output but mostly the original image with glow on top. You should set it to 1 so that you have full control if and how much glow you want to add in the *Mix RGB* node. There you just have a factor of 0.575, which means you're adding a lot of the original image on top of itself but not the full glow. Another thing is, you're plugging the denoised image into the *Glare* node. But denoising averages values which could also lead to reduced brightness and thus less glow. And by the way: the *Denoise* node works quite well and it doesn't need enabled *Sampling* > *Denoising* in the *Render Tab*. That just makes the rendering slower and the *Denoise* node in the *Compositor* works better. Actually I don't even enable *Denoising Data* when I use it, in normal scenes it doesn't make a noticeable difference. With *Denoising* enabled my render time was 47.81 seconds, without 35.10 seconds.

[image: my compositor]

Here's my *Compositor* setup:

[image: original composite]

Note that I've set *Mix* in the *Glare* node to 1 and also the *Add* factor in the *Mix RGB* node is set to 1. And the quality of the *Glare* is set to *Medium* instead of *High* - usually this is good enough and it results in more glow. With these settings I got a good glow on all objects with green and yellow at a strength of 10, red at 15 and blue with a strength of 30. The problem is, red and blue are always "darker" than green and yellow so they need higher values. Also the more saturated the values are the less bright they get, for example if you have R/G/B = (0/0/1), even multiplying by 100 will never make R and G more than 0. But with (0.01/0.01/1), R and G get higher, too which will result in emission that's turning to white the brighter it gets. I also moved the black slider on the blue emission material slightly to the left so there are less dark parts in the material.

Now for comparison, your blend file:

[image: original image]

My version, of course it looks darker because I've decreased the strength of each *Emission* shader. But since the emissions of the rings are the only light sources, the surroundings become darker, too:

[image: my version]

To compensate for that, I've made an "enhanced" version. First of all I added the picture onto itself as your setup does eventually, so it brightens up the environment. Then I've added the glow with a factor of 2 instead of 1. Now it looks like this:

[image: my enhanced version]

All in all, the crucial things are these:

1. Blue emission and also red will always be darker than green or yellow, so the effect could be less or needs more emission strength.
2. You should always set the output of the *Glare* node to 1, to show only the effect and not the original image mixed in. This way you can decide how much effect you add to the picture, especially going higher than "full effect" cannot be done with the *Mix* factor in the *Glare* node.
3. It's best to use the direct image output for the *Glare* node instead of an already denoised version, although it might not make a difference in most cases.

Here's my edited blend file, with enhanced and standard composition. I didn't pack the textures into it because that would've been too big:

[image]

Comment: thank you, lowering the threshold helped a lot. the only thing is with the emission values, originally i set them to 20 but for some reason the blue has to be set to 100 and still the glare effect isn't equal.  And the add feature is something i will be using from now on.

Comment: I can't see it in the screenshot, is the glowing part directly visible for the camera or is it behind glass? It reduces the emission strength a lot if it has to shine through glass.

Comment: I wasn't home until now and couldn't check the blend file. I will rework it a little.

Comment: @Mpizzz89 I've edited my answer to show you what I would change.

Comment: This is beyond amazing, thank you so much! my node knowledge mostly comes from youtube so not always reliable.

Comment: Generic alpha over works. No need for adds.

Comment: @troy_s Alpha over for what? And how with no alpha transparency?

Comment: @Mpizzz89 You don't have to use the nodes as I do, I'm no expert either. It's what I suggest how to have better control. For a quick and easy out of the box glow effect you can simply put the _Glare_ node between _Render Layer_ and _Composite Output_ with _Mix_ set to 0 and it mostly works fine, but especially when you want to tweak it and have more options on how to put a glow on your image it's best to separate it. You also don't have to use _Add_ in the _Mix RGB_ node, other mixing modes might bring interesting results as well. But mostly you would want _Add_ or _Lighten_ for glow.

Comment: Alpha is _occlusion_, so there’s always alpha in a light transport sense. A glow is essentially like a reflection, which is an emission with no occlusion. Given that the workhorse of light combination is the alpha over, it is trivial to integrate it properly as such. R, G, B, nonzero, and occlusion / alpha zero. Glare used to, by default, properly assemble the alpha channel.

Comment: @troy_s But in an image where there are non-glowing parts that are not transparent, they will be opaque black. So if you use _Alpha Over_ to overlay an image, it will be black where the non-glowing objects are instead of showing the underlying image. With _Add_ or _Lighten_ the black part will have no effect and leave the underlying image as it is. And using one single _Add_ node is also very trivial... not much more complicated than using a single _Alpha Over_ node. Especially when it's black in some parts. And you can't increase the glow by increasing the factor like when using _Add_.

Comment: > But in an image where there are non-glowing parts that are not transparent, they will be opaque black. < This is false, and a fundamental misunderstanding of how and what alpha models. Zero alpha means no occlusion, and the light is added as per reflection, fire, glow. Light is simply scaled. It is worth working through the math by hand to get a full handle on geometry. See also https://twitter.com/troy_s/status/1102283028896731136?s=21

Comment: @troy_s I'm just talking about what you get as output from the _Glare_ node in the _Compositor_ and how you process it further. If you know how to do with an _Alpha Over_ node what I do with _Add_ and it is so "trivial" as you put it, l'm looking forward to your answer here to make it easier.

Comment: Glare used to output alpha. Needless to say, even if it doesn’t, set alpha at zero will mean zero occlusion, and makes the image a simple over.

Comment: @troy_s "set alpha at zero" - Where? Which alpha? "a simple over"? I'm sorry I don't get it. Tell me what I'm doing wrong. Here is an image what I'm doing with _Add_ and what it looks like if I use _Alpha Over_: [image comparison](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ievana4r7OLybio1HAJxTof9fvy2XfRt/view?usp=sharing) Please tell me how I'm supposed to do it. Or here is the quite simple file: [blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tIiEyx5gLFufRzCTd-adGu0axOSq8Fxy/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: “Glows” are additive light, exactly the same as a reflection. In terms of alpha encoding, that means that the regions that are purely additive have an occlusion of zero and some nonzero RGB. So the glow region would have the emissions set to the level desired. Any degrees of occlusion, such as particulates or other geometry, have their respective occlusion degree set. Not sure what is confusing.

Comment: @troy_s Why do you explain in so many words the functionality instead of simply telling how to do this with the Glare node when it's so simple? I've given links to an image and a file... have you looked at it? What did I do wrong so it's not working? I want to learn that, please.